# Visual Studio C++ and Android Emulator?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, android-emulator

I want to make a game for android, but I don't want to program in java.

Visual Studio have support for Android applications in C++, When I start / debug application it say:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       Error installing the package. The device '' is invalid or not running.  Please switch to another device, or use the Android Virtual Device (AVD) Manager to start a compatible emulator, or connect a compatible Android device.    Android1_test.Packaging     0
```

I have installed xamarin emulator but I can't debug my project into that, and i don't have installed "Microsoft Visual Studio Emulator for Android", when I try to install it I get an error "Setup blocked" and this:

```
This computer does not support the Visual Studio Emulator for Android, which requires a 64-bit Windows 8/8.1/10 Pro/Enterprise edition or Window Server 2012 or above and a computer that supports Hyper-V. For more information, see System Requirements for Visual Studio Emulator for Android (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228280.aspx).
```

**Do I need to install "Hyper-V server 2012..." or something?**

EDIT: I have Windows 10 Home and it doesn't support Hyper-V. Thanx you Microsoft (Windows 10 Pro ($129.99) support Hyper-V)

Comment: Look closer: "which requires a 64-bit Windows 8/8.1/10 Pro/Enterprise edition or Window Server 2012 or above", "and a computer that supports Hyper-V"

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? The error message specifically mentions **64 Bit** and **Windows 8 Pro/Enterprise** or newer.

Comment: I have Windows 10 Home 64-bit, and can you give me the link for Hyper-V?

Comment: Follow the link in the error messages. It lists the requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Android with API level 9, released a way to create true C++ applications. This methodology is called NativeActivity and many popular game engines like Unreal and others use this mechanism. Visual Studio comes with the [Visual Studio Android Emulator](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/msft-android-emulator-vs.aspx) which you can download for an OOTB experience.

Hopefully this helps, if you still have other questions or issues with your experience please feel free to contact at aasthan@microsoft.com.

The [image]

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio Emulator for Android is very nice to use, but as you've discovered, it's only available on machines running a version of Windows that supports Hyper-V, which does not include the Home versions. You'll need a Pro version to get that functionality. Fortunately, that's not the only option for developing an app for Android with Visual Studio. The Android SDK comes with a basic emulator that will run on Windows 7, 8.1 or 10 Home editions, although it's not as performant (read: it makes snails look speedy). Intel has a more tolerable solution called HAXM (Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager) that you can try. HAXM is an alternative to Hyper-V specifically designed for supporting fast emulation for Android development (in other words, you can't run both HAXM and Hyper-V at the same time). To use it, you need to have a 64-bit Intel processor that supports VT-x and XD, the instructions used to enable VM support. [Intel provides installation instructions here](https://software.intel.com/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows).

Another option is just to hook up an Android device with a USB cable. Most devices let you enable Developer Options in the Settings. There are some [common instructions on enabling Developer Options](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) here, but in some cases you'll have to look up how to do that for your specific device, because it varies. When you connect an Android device to your computer with Developer Options for USB connections enabled, the device appears in the drop-down list of deployment targets in Visual Studio. You can deploy code to it directly and debug it remotely the same way you would with the emulator. Be sure to match your build configuration with the architecture of the device you're targeting. The emulators use x86 code, while most (not all) Android devices have ARM processors.